# Zend MySQL Check if a table exist

Tags: php, mysql, zend-framework

I want to know if there is a way to test if a table exists using Zend.
I'm quite new in Zend, I see in a StackOverflow answer this code.

```
SELECT 1 FROM testtable LIMIT 1;
```

But if the table doesn't exist it return an error I don't know how to handle SQL errors in the Zend.

Comment: Please tell us why you need to test for the existence of the table.  What happens next if the table does exist, and what happens if the table doesn't exist?

Comment: I just want to have a boolean that can tell me if the table exist or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the table might not exist at all, then your current query would fail if executed.  One alternative which won't crash even if the table does not exist would be to query the information schema table:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN table_schema = 'yourdb' AND table_name = 'testtable'
               THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt
FROM information_schema.tables;
```

The above query would always return a single record containing a count of matching tables.  If the above query returns a `cnt` value of 1, then the table exists, and if it returns 0, then the table does not exist.

**Edit:**

If the database and/or table names would be dynamic, coming from your PHP script, then you may use a prepared statement and bind values for the database/table dynamically.  The query does not change much:

```
SELECT
    COUNT(CASE WHEN table_schema = ? AND table_name = ? THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS cnt
FROM information_schema.tables;
```

See the [PHP documentation on prepared statements](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the answer but the database name can change in my case there is a way to have the database selected like an environment variable?

Comment: @Toothgip You may use a prepared statement in PHP and bind values dynamically for the database/table name from your script.